# Copy Redshift Pipe Delimited enclosed by double Quotes

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to load a file from S3 to Redshift. The file is delimited by Pipe, but there are value that contains Pipe and other Special characters, but if value has Pipe, it is enclosed by double quotes.

Example: 
`Field1|Field2`
`"abc|dh"|123`
`efh@ih|233`

I have tried using below command but i am getting error saying invalid digit. it is due to the copy command is considering pipe in the value as delimiter.

`copy table`
`from 's3'`
`iam_role 'arn'`
`region 'us-east-1'`
`MAXERROR AS 10 NULL AS '(null)'`
`'ESCAPE "'`
`IGNOREHEADER AS 1`
`DELIMITER '|' timeformat 'auto' GZIP;`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `REMOVEQUOTES` parameter. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-removequotes

`ESCAPE` requires your data to be prepared with the escape character embedded. For example if your escape character was `\` then you would need to prepare the data so that the content was `"abc\|dh"`.

Example:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.quote_test; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.quote_test (col_a VARCHAR(10), col_b VARCHAR(10)); 
SELECT * FROM quote_test;
```

```sh
echo '"a|b"|"c|d"' > ~/simple_quotes.txt
aws s3 cp ~/simple_quotes.txt s3://my-bucket/simple_quotes.txt
```

```sql
--Will fail
COPY quote_test FROM 's3://my-bucket/simple_quotes.txt' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/redshift-cluster'
DELIMITER '|' REGION 'us-west-2';

--Succeeds with REMOVEQUOTES
COPY quote_test FROM 's3://benchmark-files/simple_quotes.txt' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/redshift-cluster'
REMOVEQUOTES DELIMITER '|' REGION 'us-west-2';

SELECT * FROM quote_test;
--  col_a | col_b
-- -------+-------
--  a|b   | c|d
```